# How to set up host name for a new domain to point to home server?

Tags: ip, domain, hostname

I am trying to set up a Host Name for a domain so that it points to my home server but I am confused about [instructions at go daddy.com](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/680/managing-dns-for-your-domain-names).

If my domain is `mydomain.me` and my external ip address is `123.12.123.123` what do I enter in the Host field?

The instructions say:

> Host -- Enter the host name the A record links to. Type @ to map the
>   record directly to your domain name, including the www.

Do I enter `@www.mydomain.me`? Do I need `www`? Or do I just enter `@`?

And I assume that in "Host IP address" field I will add my external ip address.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@`. [It is equivalent to writing `mydomain.me`](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/apa/origin.html).

You might also want to have an additional `A` record for `www`, that points to the same IP address (your external IP address).

The `@` entry will only map `mydomain.me` to an IP address. If someone would query `www.mydomain.me`, then there wouldn't be a mapping in the zone. This is why you would want to have an additional mapping for `www`. Alternatively, you might be able to set up an entry for `*`, which would map *any* subdomain of `mydomain.me` to a specific IP address.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am still learning this stuff, can you explain why is it good to have www added as well?

Comment: @Zeynel I've added the information to the answer